Xubuntu on MacBook2,1 2006 boots to grub tty
I’m trying to install xubuntu 22.04 LTS on my MacBook2,1 from 2006. I followed these steps to get the usb booting: Installing ubuntu 20.04 on MacBook 2,1 (2007) (couldn’t do step 3 and so on because of package ng errors), then afterwards followed this guide to get the installed system booting: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/s/Fa6sZVDpff
After I type in the set root and set prefix commands. I’m presented with this at startup:
error: can't find command ‘[‘.

error: can't find command ‘[‘.

error: can't find command ‘[‘.

error: can't find command ‘[‘.

error: can't find command ‘[‘.

error: file /boot/grub/i386-efi/xzio.mod' not found. 

error: can't find command ‘[‘.

Press any key to continue…_

After pressing [ENTER], I’m booting into the desktop/login screen. Running the commands to remove shim-signed and installing grub-efi-ia32 to then run update-grub and update-grub2. I reboot.
But I’m brought back to the tty and I can still boot by setting the root and prefix but same errors and same scenario just no need to install/remove packages because they are already installed.
Steps I’ve tried to fix:

using boot repair
copying the files from /boot/efi/EFI/debian over to /boot/efi/EFI/ubunutu (one of the comments said that they had a grub tty and fixed it which copying /boot/…/pop over to /boot/…/ubuntu: https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/)

EDIT: Mistake on my part of the year release: 2006 and not 2007 thank you David Anderson

You may find better performance with Raspberry Pi OS dekstop https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/raspberry-pi-desktop/. Also, it is 32 bit, so it may have a better support for the 32 bit UEFI in this Macbook

I could install yes a 32 bit distro. Like MX Linux or Rasbian. But I wonder if it were possible to install xubuntu. Because if I’m not mistaken, a 32-bit distro limits me to 32-bit packages and a potential abandonment of development in the future of both the distro maintainers and package maintainers.

Debian releases are supported for 5 years, and Debian is not dropping 32 supports anytime soon. You will still be supported under Debian until early 2030s. If your laptop survives until then, and you still want to use the laptop at that point, decide in 2030s how to proceed next. For now, I would suggest to go on with what just works.

I already posted in your linked question that a 2007 with model identifier MacBook2,1 actually has a 64 bit EFI. Are you sure you Mac is 2007 and not 2006? Being that you have an  older Mac, you might be better off using BIOS booting over EFI booting. Partly because of Mac has an older EFI version and partly because there may be better driver support for BIOS booting. Also, are you just install Xubuntu or are you trying to install a dual boot with OS X?

When searching up the device I thought it was 2007 (so maybe it is an 2006 model) and when reading online I saw that a device had a hybrid setup. I am trying to install xubuntu only and rid the drive of MacOS. Like I stated,  I was able to get the device to boot the live usb, run the installer, rid of MacOS but when following the guide on Reddit I am stuck at the system throwing me into the grub’s tty. Again, still a belt to boot and get the desktop by setting the root and prefix.
